# on tab change update the state in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here there are two tabs invoice_specific and as_hoc and one button where I am displaying sum(this.state.sum) value .
by default when I open the screen in sum state "invoice_specific" value should come I have written this in render function below .
Now if I change the tabs I am calling function handleChangeTab() ,here on tab change I have to update the state sum .
If I am in first tab invoice_specific value should display else I am in as_hoc tab them this value should assign in sum .

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        sum: 0,
        invoice_specific: 0,
        as_hoc: 0
    }
    this.handleChangeTab = this.handleChangeTab.bind(this)
}
handleChangeTab=(obj) =>{ 
 console.log({ obj })
}
```

console value of obj in function handleChangeTab()

```
{ i: 1, ref: {…}, from: 0 }
from: 0
i: 1
ref: $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: ".1"
props:
  children: {
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
    type: ƒ,
    key: null,
    ref: null,
    props: {…},
    …
  }
  heading: "AD-HOC"
  tabLabel: "AD-HOC"
  virtual: undefined
```

return function

```
render(){
  const viewStyle = {flexDirection: 'column', padding:10, backgroundColor: '#fff', minHeight:deviceHeight }
  return( 
    <Tabs onChangeTab={(obj)=> this.handleChangeTab(obj)}>
        <Tab heading="INVOICE SPECIFIC" tabLabel="SPECIFIC">
        <View style={viewStyle}>
            <RegularText text="Enter Specific Amount to pay" style={{paddingBottom:5}} textColor="#959595" />
            <View>
            <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                <Input autoFocus={true} 
                       onPress={()=> this.handleChange('sumValue')} 
                       onChangeText={(sumValue) => this.handleChangeSum(sumValue)} />
            </Item>
            </View>
        </View>
        </Tab>
        <Tab heading="AD-HOC" tabLabel="AD-HOC">
        <View style={viewStyle}>
            <RegularText text="Enter Specific Amount to pay" style={{paddingBottom:5}} textColor="#959595" />
            <View>
            <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
                <Input autoFocus={true}
                       onPress={()=> this.handleChange('sumValue')}
                       onChangeText={(sumValue) => this.handleChangeSum(sumValue)} />
            </Item>
            </View>
        </View>
        </Tab>
    </Tabs> 
  ) 
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: when I am changing the tab sum is not getting update

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see that you have called setState() anywhere. You need to call setState appropriately while avoiding infinite re-rendering. Also if you can go further and change it to a functional component where you would find ref and useEffect make the code much more simpler and readable.